# How to set value of multiple parameters on a single button click?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, httprequest

I have a JSP page with only a single button. For example a Student button.
When i click on my student, I need to set 2 parameters in my httpRequest(viewName as student and modelName as StudentDetails).
And when i call `request.getParameter("viewName")` or `request.getParameter("modelName")` in my controller class , i want to get `student` or `StudentDetails`.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Use '&' to append multiple parameters with in URL. E.g. http://localhost?viewName=student&modelName=studentDetails.

Comment: could you please show here how to achieve this? A code snippet will be appreciable

Comment: Follow this link. https://jsfiddle.net/parth9365/qpth4wbw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript to set those values into hidden field on button click in your form

eg:-

```
<input type="hidden" id="viewname" name="viewName" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="modelname"  name="modelName" value="">
<button onclick="onButtonClickFn()">Submit</button>

function onButtonClickFn(){
document.getElementById("viewname").value = "your-value1";
document.getElementById("modelname").value = "your-value2";
}
```

Comment: but how can you  set value of input fields dynamically inside javascript code ?

Comment: if the values are dynamic, create one API to return those values and make an ajax API call on button click.